# Changing identification settings in Sublime doesn't work for certain existing files

Tags: sublimetext3

In my `Sublime` user settings I have `"tab_size": 2`, which works great for all new files. But some third party files seem to have their own identification settings embedded into them somehow (in which case my user settings have no effect).

How to overcome them?

Answer (score 0):

The `"tab_size"` setting is only for new files and existing files that use tabs (instead of spaces) for indentation. If a file uses spaces (which I suspect yours do), Sublime will automatically determine the indentation size. You would need to reindent the file to match your preferred tab size.

Comment: Thanks but in these files, the very identification "behavior" is altered: pressing tab moves cursor 4 spaces to the right (instead of 2 as specified in user settings)

Comment: @drake035 That's what I said in my 2nd sentence - if I send you a Python file indented with 4 spaces per tab, even though your preferences say `"tab_size": 2`, if you hit Tab in my file it will indent 4 spaces. You'd need to reindent the file (not always an easy task) to 2 spaces per block for your preference to work.

Comment: However, if I send you a file using actual tabs for indentation (the `\t` character), it should show up as being equivalent to 2 spaces on your end.

Comment: Not sure how to check whether my file is indented with spaces of tabs. When putting the cursor right at the beginning of the first word of a line with a tab at the beginning (that is, cursor after the tab but before the first letter) then hit delete, this jumps over the whole tab back to the absolute beginning of the line, not just one space. So I guess tabs were used rather than spaces? None of this tells me exactly how to get my 2-spaces tabs back though.

Comment: @drake035 Put your cursor at the very beginning of an indented line and press the right arrow. If it's tab-indented, your cursor will move the distance indicated in the bottom bar (such as `Tab Width: 4`). If it's space-indented, the cursor will move 1 space.